Did not find benchmarking metadata, Other: Exported method Benchmark_benchmark_metadata is not found
I am trying to benchmark Frame pallets for my runtime and am unsure what to add before actually benchmarking them. I am on an very old substrate release branch. With my current setup even when I try to list the benchmarks I get an error as follows.
./target/release/borderless benchmark pallet --chain borderless --list
Error: Input("Did not find the benchmarking metadata. This could mean that you either did not build the node correctly with the `--features runtime-benchmarks` flag, or the chain spec that you are using was not created by a node that was compiled with the flag: Other: Exported method Benchmark_benchmark_metadata is not found")

I am pretty sure I built my node with the following:
cargo build --release --features runtime-benchmarks

Additionally, I have also generated the chain-spec with the following command.
./target/release/borderless --chain=borderless --raw --disable-default-bootnode > borderless.chainspec.json

Now my borderless runtime looks as follows.
In lib.rs i have
#[cfg(feature = "runtime-benchmarks")]
#[macro_use]
extern crate frame_benchmarking;

#[cfg(feature = "runtime-benchmarks")]
mod benches {
    define_benchmarks!(
        [frame_system, SystemBench::<Runtime>]
        [pallet_utility, Utility]
        [pallet_multisig, Multisig]
        [pallet_proxy, Proxy]
        [pallet_scheduler, Scheduler]
        [pallet_preimage, Preimage]
        [pallet_indices, Indices]
        [pallet_balances, Balances]
        [frame_benchmarking::baseline, Baseline::<Runtime>]
        // There are more pallets which i have removed for now.
    );
}

Implemented the Benchmark trait for my runtime.
#[cfg(feature = "runtime-benchmarks")]
    impl frame_benchmarking::Benchmark<Block> for Runtime {

        fn benchmark_metadata(extra: bool) -> (
            Vec<frame_benchmarking::BenchmarkList>,
            Vec<frame_support::traits::StorageInfo>,
            ) {
            use frame_benchmarking::{list_benchmark, Benchmarking, BenchmarkList};
            use frame_support::traits::StorageInfoTrait;
            use frame_system_benchmarking::Pallet as SystemBench;
            use frame_benchmarking::baseline::Pallet as Baseline;

            let mut list = Vec::<BenchmarkList>::new();

            list_benchmark!(list, extra, frame_system, SystemBench::<Runtime>);

            let storage_info = AllPalletsWithSystem::storage_info();

            return (list, storage_info)
    }

        fn dispatch_benchmark(
            config: frame_benchmarking::BenchmarkConfig
        ) -> Result<Vec<frame_benchmarking::BenchmarkBatch>, sp_runtime::RuntimeString> {
            use frame_benchmarking::{Benchmarking, BenchmarkBatch, add_benchmark, TrackedStorageKey};

            use frame_system_benchmarking::Pallet as SystemBench;
            use frame_benchmarking::baseline::Pallet as Baseline;
            impl frame_system_benchmarking::Config for Runtime {}
            impl frame_benchmarking::baseline::Config for Runtime {}
            //A vec of Tracked Storage key which i am omitting for now while asking.
            let mut batches = Vec::<BenchmarkBatch>::new();
            let params = (&config, &whitelist);

            add_benchmark!(params, batches, frame_system, SystemBench::<Runtime>);

            if batches.is_empty() { return Err("Benchmark not found for this pallet.".into()) }
            Ok(batches)
        }
    }


I have put the frame-system and frame-system-benchmarking as dependencies in the toml file and also have a feature called runtime-benchmarks.
runtime-benchmarks = [
    "frame-benchmarking",
    "frame-support/runtime-benchmarks",
    "frame-system/runtime-benchmarks",
    "frame-system-benchmarking",
    "pallet-utility/runtime-benchmarks",
    "pallet-multisig/runtime-benchmarks",
    "pallet-proxy/runtime-benchmarks",
    "pallet-scheduler/runtime-benchmarks",
    "pallet-multisig/runtime-benchmarks",
    "pallet-preimage/runtime-benchmarks",
    "pallet-indices/runtime-benchmarks",
    "pallet-balances/runtime-benchmarks",
]

I am also parsing command line arguments into a service configuration which then matches the subcommand and benchmarks the chain.
Can you enlighten me why am i facing this error? I am pretty lost at this point.

Ensure that your borderless node was also compiled with the runtime-benchmarks feature. Do you forward the feature in your node to the runtime?

I have something like
runtime-benchmarks = [
"borderless-runtime/runtime-benchmarks",
"frame-benchmarking-cli",
]
in node/cli/cargo.toml. Is this what you mean by forwarding? If not can you direct me on how this is done in polkadot or any other chain?

I also have
borderless-runtime = { path = "../runtime" }

@bkchr any suggestion, please? I am matching the subcommand as given in the note link.
https://pastebin.com/PmyTTvjz

also, I am a bit unsure what the new_partial does.
